Converting complex Formula into Dynamic Array
Trying to create a Dynamic array from a somewhat complex formula but keep getting #N/A errors randomly.

For some reason, the y value of the equations doesn't like it.
Effectively the #N/A for the first instance is saying it can't find 0.57 in the particle diameter table on the left, despite clearly being listed.
Data to mimic:
Table1:



Particle Diameter δ (μm)
Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)
γ(δ)




0.00
0
0.000555556


0.19
2.33195E-15
0.000556338


0.38
5.3411E-15
0.000558686


0.57
7.49672E-15
0.000562599


0.76
8.93319E-15
0.000568078


0.95
9.85973E-15
0.000575121


1.14
1.04323E-14
0.00058373


1.33
1.07581E-14
0.000593905


1.52
1.09105E-14
0.000605644


1.71
1.09403E-14
0.000618949


1.90
1.0883E-14
0.000633819


2.09
1.07639E-14
0.000650254



InputParameters:



Spray Duration (minutes)




11.1



Problematic Formula:
=MAKEARRAY(10,11,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x*7.8 <= InputParameters[[Spray Duration (minutes)]:[Spray Duration (minutes)]] * 60,

XLOOKUP(y*0.19, Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]:[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]]) *
    (1 - EXP(-XLOOKUP(y*0.19, Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) * x*7.8)) /
    XLOOKUP(y*0.19, Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]),

XLOOKUP(y*0.19, Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]:[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]]) /
    XLOOKUP(y*0.19, Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) *
    (1 - EXP(-XLOOKUP(y*0.19, Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) * (InputParameters[[Spray Duration (minutes)]:[Spray Duration (minutes)]] * 60))) *
    EXP(-XLOOKUP(y*0.19, Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) * (x*7.8 - (InputParameters[[Spray Duration (minutes)]:[Spray Duration (minutes)]] * 60)))
)))

Correct data (When using the long formula and dragging) (particle size on top, Time down the LHS):



TIME (s)
0
0.19
0.38
0.57
0.76
0.95




0
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00
0.00E+00


7.80
0.00E+00
1.81E-14
4.16E-14
5.83E-14
6.95E-14
7.67E-14


15.60
0.00E+00
3.62E-14
8.30E-14
1.16E-13
1.39E-13
1.53E-13


23.40
0.00E+00
5.42E-14
1.24E-13
1.74E-13
2.08E-13
2.29E-13


31.20
0.00E+00
7.21E-14
1.65E-13
2.32E-13
2.76E-13
3.05E-13


39.00
0.00E+00
9.00E-14
2.06E-13
2.89E-13
3.45E-13
3.80E-13


46.80
0.00E+00
1.08E-13
2.47E-13
3.46E-13
4.13E-13
4.55E-13


54.60
0.00E+00
1.25E-13
2.87E-13
4.03E-13
4.80E-13
5.30E-13


62.40
0.00E+00
1.43E-13
3.28E-13
4.60E-13
5.48E-13
6.04E-13


70.20
0.00E+00
1.61E-13
3.68E-13
5.16E-13
6.15E-13
6.78E-13


78.00
0.00E+00
1.78E-13
4.08E-13
5.72E-13
6.82E-13
7.52E-13


85.80
0.00E+00
1.95E-13
4.47E-13
6.28E-13
7.48E-13
8.25E-13



LINK TO WORKBOOK IN IMAGE:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsrLaUgt0KCLxXOWIrFQWEaQoxky?e=vnORUu
Update1 Adding &"":

Update2 Adding TRUE and Setting y*0.19 to the array


You're only showing the (expected) result, not any of the data you're linking to which is necessary for us to reproduce. Please post some sample data and expected results from that (you could make use of https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to post a table as data)

Agree, Was trying to keep the question shorter. Will upload link to workbook if that's okay.

appreciate this isn't standard practice but for ease please see:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsrLaUgt0KCLxXFz-a8xYT9QQBbb?e=wqugjk

@P.b Sorry for being lazy yesterday I have re-written the question in a simpler format and provided all data and a link to replicate

A per latest question it seems xlookup doesn't actually function well in Makearray

@Nick to your last question, found if you are not able to use ROUND() then adding "" should also work: =MAKEARRAY(5,6,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP((y*0.19)&"",Table1[A]&"",Table1[B]))) to get exact matches

@MayukhBhattacharya This improves the result but still getting #N/A in some instances

@Nick like for example?

@Nick will it be right to use TRUNC() or is it also excluded : =MAKEARRAY(5,6,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(TRUNC(y*0.19,2),Table1[A],Table1[B])))

@MayukhBhattacharya Please See Update 1 Image. Note in the image I miss &"" in the at the end in the picture but adding it in reality still yields the same result.

@MayukhBhattacharya I would like to avoid any shortcuts like that because I can guarantee it will always be an exact match to n number of decimal places. This is more to understand what the issue the function may be having. It is a glitch in excel?

@Nick agree, may be its a glitch, bt dont think its a rounding problem. I have checked.

@MayukhBhattacharya There's 2 things going in this formula. When x*7.8 is less than the spray duration which for the value sin this screenshot all evaluate to true to run the first block. so even though it is missed it should work as the if statement returns true for the values in the screenshot. That being said I have corrected for all and it still fails.

Just never really seen a glicth in excel. Its almost always something Ive missed..

@Nick it is strange when used ROUNDING() it worked or with "" even though it is exact match there is no extra decimal exactly same values. not sure why it is happening, i am still trying to figure it out. if i come up will update else i give up lol  think not my cup of tea then but i will try

@Nick to validate i just used this to find whether there is any rounding issues or not found there is none. =MAKEARRAY(5,6,LAMBDA(x,y,y*0.19)) still not working with exact match

Yes, I realised this too in the simpler follow up question. XLOOKUP doesn't seem to like y*0.19 for some random values of y. Very odd that sometimes it works.

@Nick it is a rounding problem only, try using XMATCH() or MATCH() function and then use EXACT() function you will understand. So ROUNDING() is needed!

do we know why y*0.19 where y = 3 needs to be rounded?
Also please could you provide an example of the full formula. for the last question. No need to do the full one here

This one: =MAKEARRAY(5,6,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(TRUNC(y*0.19,2),Table1[A],Table1[B])))

With formulas like this, it's usually best to remove redundancy so you can see what's going on more easily.
This seems to work:
=MAKEARRAY(
    10,
    11,
    LAMBDA(x, y,
        LET(
            columnLookup, ROUND(y * 0.19, 2),
            particleDiameter, ROUND(Table1[Particle Diameter δ (μm)], 2),
            sprayDuration, TAKE(InputParameters[Spray Duration (minutes)], 1, 1),
            gammaOfDelta, XLOOKUP(columnLookup, particleDiameter, Table1[γ(δ)]),
            rairBorne, XLOOKUP(columnLookup, particleDiameter, Table1[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]),
            IF(
                x * 7.8 <= sprayDuration * 60,
                rairBorne * (1 - EXP(-gammaOfDelta * x * 7.8)) / gammaOfDelta,
                rairBorne / gammaOfDelta * (1 - EXP(-gammaOfDelta * (sprayDuration * 60))) *
                    EXP(-gammaOfDelta * (x * 7.8 - (sprayDuration * 60)))
            )
        )
    )


As an aside, MAKEARRAY is a slow function. It's better to use SEQEUNCE if you can, so in my version I've used SEQUENCE for the row and column headers:
=SEQUENCE(11,,7.8,7.8)
=SEQUENCE(,11,0.19,0.19)


This has to do with floating point calculation: https://spreadsheetweb.com/floating-point-calculation-issues-excel/
A workaround could be using index referring to your cells rather than a calculation of these values:
=MAKEARRAY(10,11,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x*7.8<=Table2[Spray Duration (minutes)] * 60,XLOOKUP(INDEX(J4:T4,,y), Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]:[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]]) *    (1 - EXP(-XLOOKUP(INDEX(J4:T4,,y), Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) * x*7.8)) /    XLOOKUP(INDEX(J4:T4,,y), Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]),XLOOKUP(INDEX(J4:T4,,y), Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]:[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]]) /    XLOOKUP(INDEX(J4:T4,,y), Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) *    (1 - EXP(-XLOOKUP(INDEX(J4:T4,,y), Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) * (Table2[Spray Duration (minutes)]* 60))) *    EXP(-XLOOKUP(INDEX(J4:T4,,y), Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]]) * (x*7.8 - (Table2[Spray Duration (minutes)] * 60))))))
(I used Table2, since in the app version I'm unable to change the table's name).

This is largely the best solution. I have approached a different way by just adding an additional index column to then perform the lookup on. Not a fan of these sort of work around but seems the floating point problem is not straightforward to resolve

Remember that this can be optimised using LET, as @FlexYourData demonstrated.
