Xlookup in excel doesnt function in Makearray?
There appears to be an error in excel formula when combining XLOOKUP with MAKEARRAY formula:
e.g.

This is a simplified example.  I have used y values of constant increments to make the formula easier to highlight the error however this isn't necessarily the case. In reality, there may be a different way to introduce y values.
Despite the maths being correct i.e. 0.19*3 = 0.570 I get a #N/A error. We would have expected C.
But then strangely it does works on the next line i.e. 0.19*4 = 0.760 and returns D as desired.
I would like to avoid any assumptions e.g. rounding or using the next closest value as the values are exact (Except in my previous question where I make a mistake with the data).
Data to mimic:



A
B




0.190
A


0.380
B


0.570
C


0.760
D


0.950
E


1.140
F


1.330
G


1.520
H


1.710
I


1.900
J



Formula:
=MAKEARRAY(3,10,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP((y*0.19),Table1[A],Table1[B])))

Even more confusingly if I specify y exactly:
=MAKEARRAY(3,10,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP((0.570),Table1[A],Table1[B])))


it works so it should always be an exact match.
So there is some issue with saying y*0.19
Rounding and using XLOOKUP With a non-exact match may get the right answer but I don't think its acceptable for the question here because the values are always and exact match and I want to understand what the problem then is.
i.e. Why doesn't y*0.19 when y = 3 match to the 0.570 in column A, given that it does match is 0.57 is specified exactly (without using y).
apologies for not being clearer in the previous question.
Update 1:
Using True y*0.19=Array


This also works =MAKEARRAY(5,10,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(TRUE,y*0.19=Table1[A],Table1[B]))) but I know it's not getting us much nearer to the root cause.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work on the original question: Please see update 2. I have highlighted the changes in pink and you can see it still returns #N/A
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78450550/converting-complex-formula-into-dynamic-array

Well we've established that the xlookup works with (say) y=7 so the logical conclusion is that the long formula is going wrong for some other reason. What I suggest is that you use =let(x,1,y,7.....rest of your long formula) and step through it using Evaluate Formula to see where it's getting the #N/A from. Having said that, if it's possible to replace the .19 by 19 and do everything with integers, that would be a much better way to go,.

@TomSharpe Unfortunately Im not sure we have established the Xlookup works. coincidently When y = 7  it doesn't work in the above image (update 1).  So I'm not sure at this stage we can conclude the rest of the larger formula was wrong.

OK let me post a screenshot

I have taken the liberty of pasting my formula into your dynamic sheet. My formula does not work in your sheet so now we have to work out why.

OK, you are right, the xlookup fails for y=7 in your online sheet so we are back to looking for other methods. I assume you are using online excel in your productions not just for demo?

Hi Nick, while I also cannot figure out the root cause, I'm not sure why using ROUND(y*0.19,2)=Table1[A] works; 2 or higher also seem to work. I understand you're not inclined to use rounding, but have you tried in your actual formula?

Also, I'm curious as to why you're not using INDEX(Table1[B],y) in this particular case.

Excel is storing 3*0.19 as 0.57000000000000006 so an exact match with 0.57 will fail. This is a consequence of the documented Floating Point Error problem

@RonRosenfeld Ah okay! Any way around this to specify the exact number?

@nkalvi To be honest Rounding to enough decimal places could work but I suppose both on principal but also just curiosity I want to know what the issue was and how to solve it exactly.

@Nick The two accepted techniques are to use either rounding, or testing that the difference is not greater than a very small amount. In your issue, I would suggest rounding to an appropriate level of precision. You could use VBA and the Decimal data type, but that is not available as a worksheet function and executes much more slowly.

Please see updated formula using min absolute difference

Please see original question for background to this. The problem was that Xlookup gave #N/A for some values of y*0.19 where y is an integer although matching values were present. The initial workaround
Xlookup(true,y*.19=[Lookup table column],[Return table column])

worked on Excel 365 but not as it turned out in Excel online.
The original test data was posted in this Excel online sheet.
These are my results in Excel 365:

or (not sure if I had it aligned with the right row)

The lookup part of the formula (e.g. for y=7) works in my Excel 365 but gives #N/A in the online sheet:
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,7*0.19= Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]], Table1[[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]:[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]])

So now you would be looking at other standard methods which usually involve min absolute difference or similar.
Try this instead of Xlookup:
=@SORTBY(Table1[[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]:[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]],ABS(7*0.19- Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]]), 1)

Here is the result of substituting the ABS based formula for the two different lookups into the main formula:
=MAKEARRAY(10,11,LAMBDA(x,y,

LET(
lookup1,@SORTBY(Table1[[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]:[Rairborne(δ) (kg/s)]],ABS(y*0.19- Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]]), 1),
lookup2,@SORTBY(Table1[[γ(δ)]:[γ(δ)]],ABS(y*0.19- Table1[[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]:[Particle Diameter δ (μm)]]),1 ),

IF(x*7.8 <= InputParameters[[Spray Duration (minutes)]:[Spray Duration (minutes)]] * 60,

lookup1 *
    (1 - EXP(-lookup2 * x*7.8)) /
    lookup2,

lookup1 /
    lookup2 *
    (1 - EXP(-lookup2 * (InputParameters[[Spray Duration (minutes)]:[Spray Duration (minutes)]] * 60))) *
    EXP(-lookup2 * (x*7.8 - (InputParameters[[Spray Duration (minutes)]:[Spray Duration (minutes)]] * 60)))
))))

This works in Excel 365 and Excel online. Result in online sheet:


You should be able to access OP's online copy at https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=8BA0D02D4869CBCA%218947&authkey=!AJYisVBYRpCjGTI
